# Highstock - tooltip position on iOS

Tags: highcharts

I have an issue with highstock chart tooltip, when the user moves the finger across the chart quickly.

Say the chart is for Jan 2014 to May 2014, and the user starts (touches) at Feb 1 and quickly moves the finger to Feb 15 and takes the finger off the screen. The tooltip follows the finger from Feb 1 to 15, but goes back to Feb 1. I guess because of the 300ms(?) delay, iOS thinks the last position was at Feb 1?

Any idea how to fix this issue? I would like to have the tooltip stay at Feb 15, or hide the tooltip on the chart when the finger is off the screen.

PS: We are using highstock version 1.2.4. This is on an iPad.

Thanks.

Comment: At the beginning please update to the newest (2.0.1) and let us know which iOS you have

Comment: Unfortunately, it will be few months before we will be able to update to the latest highstock version. We are using iOS versions 7.0.4.